# enum class in c++ -replacement- in c#

Tags: c#, c++, class, enums

Take a look at these **c++** codes :

```
enum class Flag : int32 {
    f_unread = (1 << 0),
    f_out = (1 << 1),
    f_mentioned = (1 << 4),

    MAX_FIELD = (1 << 4),
};
```

What is the covert of those codes in **c#**?

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx.

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Based on msdn n C# we have two names for combination of enum-class, but in c++ we have one name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using Tangible](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Free_Editions.html). Seems like it is not far different.

```
[Flags]
public enum Flag : int
{
    f_unread = (1 << 0),
    f_out = (1 << 1),
    f_mentioned = (1 << 4),

    MAX_FIELD = (1 << 4),
}
```

In c#, to use `enum` as bit field for flags operation, it should be added with `FlagsAttribute`, which adds `[FlagsAttribute]` or `[Flags]` before the `enum`.

Comment: Add the [Flags] attribute to the enum declaration when a variable of that enum type can have a combination of the values defined by the enum.

Comment: You don't need the `: int` - that's the default.

Comment: @Matthew Watson I think `: int ` should be there, cause during work on enum members you will get at error about integer type.

Comment: @MoonLight No, the default underlying type for enums is `int`, so it's not necessary to specify this unless you want `short` or `long` etc. in fact, for `[Flags]` enums, you might sometimes want to consider using `uint`, if the top bit is set in any of the enum values.