# Q_DECLARE_FLAGS in c++ -replacement- in c#

Tags: c#, c++, flags

Take a look at these **c++** codes :

```
enum class Flag : int32 {
    f_unread = (1 << 0),
    f_out = (1 << 1),
    f_mentioned = (1 << 4),

    MAX_FIELD = (1 << 15),
};

Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Flags, Flag);

friend inline Flags operator~(Flag v)
{
   return QFlag(~static_cast<int32>(v));
}
```

**My Questions :**

1. What do exactly `Q_DECLARE_FLAGS` function do and what is the replacement of it in **c#**?
2. What are `Flags` & `QFlag`?

Would you please convert those codes to **c#**!

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387986/enum-class-in-c-replacement-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296126/1997232). You didn't explain yourself clearly, it seems you have understanding what it's about [bit flags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8447/1997232), so why do you need `operator~` in `C#`?

Comment: I read the second link and it was very useful and i completely understood it. but i'm not familiar with `QT` and really dotn't know what are those codes doing. Just explain it for me by an example.